# How to browse or search software package list with the right version naming?

Tags: apt, ppa

I want to install a specific version of ipython (0.13.1), but it kept telling me that particular version does not exist. I am wondering if I am using the wrong version name, so it can not match the version I want to what is available out there.

Thank you!

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you running? The latest repository version in 12.04 for ipython 0.12.1. This does pull some backports and bugfixes from 0.13

Comment: And with 12.10, Synaptic shows ipython 0.13.1~rc3-0ubuntu1 is available.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't know much about doing this sort of thing, but have you tried looking at the [ipython GitHub](https://github.com/ipython/ipython)?

The [installation instructions](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/install/install.html#installing-ipython-itself) can be found on their site, and it seems pretty easy if you can use either of their installation scripts.

---

As for using one of ubuntu's package managers to find a differing version, I have no idea. :/

Answer (score 0):

We faced same problem, we had to install a pkg which was pretty old and was not available in pkg manager. Only solution was to compile and install manually. It gave lots of error but it finally worked.